# Solving $\sqrt{3\cos^2 x - \sin 2x} = - \sin x$

Tags: trigonometry

Please, can you suggest something for solving this equation: I have to find the solutions included in interval $\left[3\pi/2, 2\pi\right]$:
 $$\sqrt{3\cos^2 x - \sin 2x} = - \sin x$$

This is what I did:
$$\begin{array}{crcl}
\Longrightarrow & 3\cos^2 x - \sin 2x &=& \sin^2 x \\
\Longrightarrow &3\left(1-\sin^2 x\right)-\sin 2x &=& \sin^2 x \\
\Longrightarrow & 4\sin^2 x + \sin 2x - 3 &=& 0 \\
\Longrightarrow &2\left(1-\cos 2x\right)+\sin 2x - 3 &=& 0\\
\Longrightarrow &-2\cos 2x + \sin 2x &=& 1\end{array}$$

So, what's next?! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just found : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656036/determine-the-solutions-of-the-equation-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

We have $$1-\sin2x+2\cos2x=0$$

Using [Double-Angle Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html), $$1-\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+2\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=0$$ where $t=\tan x$

Solve the Quadratic Equation in $\tan x$

As $x\in\left[\frac{3\pi}2,2\pi\right], t=\tan x<0$

Comment: Thank you , I will try now!

Comment: @user123499, yes please revert if you have any confusion

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle-2=r\cos\phi,1=r\sin\phi$ where $r>0$ so $\displaystyle\frac\pi2<\phi<\pi$ and $\displaystyle\tan\phi=-\frac12$

So we have $$r\cos(2x-\phi)=r\sin\phi$$

$$\implies \cos(2x-\phi)=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\phi\right)$$

$$\implies 2x-\phi=2n\pi\pm\left(\frac\pi2-\phi\right)$$ where $n$ is any integer

Considering '+' sign, $\displaystyle2x-\phi=2n\pi+\left(\frac\pi2-\phi\right)\implies 2x=2n\pi+\frac\pi2$

Considering '-' sign, $\displaystyle2x-\phi=2n\pi-\left(\frac\pi2-\phi\right)=2n\pi-\frac\pi2+\phi\implies 2x=2n\pi+2\phi-\frac\pi2$

Comment: But can you tell me please, why do we have 2x−ϕ=2nπ±(π/2−ϕ) but not simply 2x−ϕ=π/2−ϕ?

Comment: @user123499, as $\cos(-A)=\cos A$ and  $\cos(2m\pi+y)=\cos y$

Comment: I know this , but I don't understand why do we write 2x−ϕ=2nπ±(π/2−ϕ) with 2πk?

Comment: @user123499, as we have to find $x$ somewhere outside $[0,\frac\pi2]$

Comment: @JohnG., my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

from your last step
1−sin2x+2cos2x=0
=>(sin^2x+cos^2x)-2sinxcosx+2(cos^x-sin^2x)=0
=>3cos^2x-2sinxcosx-sin^2x=0
=>3cos^2x-3sinxcosx+sinxcosx-sin^2x=0
=>3cosx(cosx-sinx)+sinx(cosx-sinx)=0
=>(cosx-sinx)(3cosx+sinx)=0
=>cosx-sinx=0 or, 3cosx+sinx=0
=>tanx=1, or tanx=-3
=>x=π/4, or x=2π/3

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{3\cos^2(x)-\sin(2x)}=-\sin(x)$

You square the both sides

$3\cos^2(x)-\sin(2x)=\sin^2(x)$

By using double angle identity of $\sin$ and dividing all the terms by $\cos^2(x)$

$\tan^2(x)+2\tan(x)-3=0$

Quadratic equation

$\tan(x)=1\text{ or }-3$

Find all the solutions in the interval

$x=5.03\text{rad}$

don't forget to check this value in the original equation.

Here when you substitute this value in the equation it equals zero but if the interval is $[0,2\pi]$, one of the solutions is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ but it doesn't work, it works if the right side is $\sin(x)$ not $-\sin(x)$.